# How to load data checked on JsTree

Tags: jquery, jstree

i wonder, how to load a new data on JsTree, i have to load data on click like this:

```
 function showTree(group_id){
        $("#jstree").jstree({
            "core": {
                "themes": {
                    'name': 'proton',
                    'responsive': true
                },
                "data": {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "/menu/tree",
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: {
                         group_id: group_id
                   },
                   success: function (data) {
                      data.d;
                      console.log(data);
                      $(data).each(function () {
                         return { "id": this.id };
                      });
                   }
                },
             },
            "checkbox" : {
                "keep_selected_style" : false
            },
            "plugins" : [ "checkbox" , "types", "json_data"]
        });
}
```

When i call function on the first time its' working but the second time with different data the data doesn't change.

Note : the different data is from checked value

data example :
new:

```
   {
      id          : "1"
      text        : "Test 1"
      state       : {
        selected  : true
      },
    }
    {
      id          : "2"
      text        : "Test 2"
      state       : {
        selected  : false
      },
    }
```

> i change to :

```
{
  id          : "1"
  text        : "Test 1"
  state       : {
    selected  : false
  },
}
{
  id          : "2"
  text        : "Test 2"
  state       : {
    selected  : false
  },
}
```

can i change only data selected from JsTree?

Answer (score 0):

The jsTree initialization with `$("#jstree").jstree()` is a one time thing and is not meant to be re-used. Calling the `jstree` function on the element again might not re-create the tree. If you're using ajax sourced data you can use jsTree's functions to re-draw with new data.

The refresh function can load new data from the ajax url.

```
function updateTree(group_id){
    $("#jstree").jstree(true).settings.core.data = {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/menu/tree",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
             group_id: group_id
        },
        success: function (data) {
          data.d;
          console.log(data);
          $(data).each(function () {
             return { "id": this.id };
          });
        }
    };

    $("#jstree").jstree(true).refresh();
}
```

Comment: if i using $("#jstree").jstree(true).refresh(); the combobox doesn't checked although json using "selected  : true"

Comment: I'm sorry I am not sure I understand that